# Secondary fonts for Chinese characters

Tags: css, localization, internationalization

Is there any way in CSS to specify a different font to be used just for Chinese characters?

Specifically, I have some user inputted text which can contain either standard English, Han characters or a mix of both. I'd like to use Myriad Pro for non-Han characters, and Kaiti Std for all Han characters.

I realize this can be done by running over the content with JavaScript, adding span tags around the Chinese characters and then applying styles to them, but is there any more standard/efficient way?

I don't care about old browsers, although it should work in the latest version of Chrome/Firefox/Safari/IE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify a `unicode-range` for font-faces so that that each font only applies to a subset of unicode characters.

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-fonts/#composite-fonts

A very basic implementation would look something like (adjust for font files and formats as needed):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFonts';
    src: local('Kaiti Std');
    unicode-range: U+4E00-9FFF;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFonts';
    src: local('Myriad Pro');
}

body {
    font-family: 'MyFonts', sans-serif;
}
```

Some interesting browser quirks/work-arounds documented at http://24ways.org/2011/creating-custom-font-stacks-with-unicode-range/